# Is it possible to have "nested" methods for multiple classes in R?

Tags: r, class

Say a have two objects:

```
a = 1:3
class(a) = append("myclass", class(a))
class(a)
[1] "myclass" "integer"

b = c("a", "b", "c")
class(b) = append("myclass", class(b))
class(b)
[1] "myclass"   "character"
```

Is it then possible to define *nested* methods which would depend **both** on "myclass" and the basic/other custom class? E.g.

```
print.myclass.integer = function(x) { some code }
print.myclass.character = function(x) { different code }
```

If so, what is the correct procedure?

Comment: Not in S3, I think. S4 does multiple dispatch based on arguments, which isn't quite what you want I think. Beyond that you're probably going to need to turn to reference classes or R6, I'd guess.

Answer (score 1):

You can work around by checking inside `print.myclass` the other classes of the object. For instance:

```
print.myclass<-function(x,...) {
     if ("integer" %in% class(x)) print("some code") else 
        if ("character" %in% class(x)) print("some other code")
}
a
#[1] "some code"
b
#[1] "some other code"
```

Comment: Or, to keep is dispatch-y, `if ("integer %in% class(x)) print.myclass.integer(x, ...))`

Comment: Hmm, this seems quite flexible. I'll get back to you after some experimentation.

Answer (score 0):

To have nested methods for multiples classes you just have to nest `UseMethod()`:

```
print.myclass <- function(x) {
  UseMethod("print.myclass", x)
}

print.myclass.integer <- function(x) {
  print(paste("This method only prints the higher 'x': ", max(x)))
}

print.myclass.character <- function(x) {
  cat("This method scrambles the 'x' values:\n")
  print(sample(x, length(x)))
}

print(a) # [1] "This method only prints the hihger 'x':  3"
print(b) #This method scrambles the 'x' values:
         # [1] "a" "c" "b"
```

When you use `print()`, it will call `UseMethod()`, which will check for a `myclass` method. Then, it will call `UseMethod()` once more and it's now going to check for a method to the second class (`integer` or `character`) for the `print.myclass` function.

Take a look at `?UseMethod`, `methods(print)` and [The R Language Definition](https://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-release/R-lang.pdf), p.28-31; it helped me out.

Comment: Hm, interesting. Are there any issues with this approach when exporting methods in a package?

Comment: I'm not sure. Why do you think there would be any?